# 1 000 + топиков в kafka или какую выбрать систему для разбития на маленькие очереди

Tags: python-3.x, архитектура, redis, apache-kafka

У меня есть система, которая принимает запросы на обработку сообщений. Она может обрабатывать 1000+ сообщений параллельно (не сложные но монотонные операции). Она разделена на 2 части: сервис приема сообщений (FastAPI) и сервис обработки (COCS, тоже python).
Каждое сообщение имеет поле group_id. Оно не привязано к какой-то статике и практически каждый день добавляются новые group_id. За день я могу принять ~1 000 сообщений и все они разделены на ~200 групп (числа только для примера). Обработка одного сообщения занимает ~2сек и главное - сообщения из одной группы должны обрабатываться последовательно, сообщения из разных групп могут обрабатываться параллельно.
Я реализовал это логику используя dict{group_id: list()}. В dict сортируется по группе, в list складывается последовательность. После обработки удаляется. Демон следит за статусами.
Если приложение перезагрузится - все данные из памяти в обработке потеряются.
Если произойдет всплеск нагрузки, контейнер схлопнется из-за OOM.
Если надо увеличить пропускной канал, масштабировать можно только вертикально.
Поэтому я хочу вынести очереди на какую-то стороннюю систему.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот тут возникает вопрос, какая систему для этого лучше всего подойдет? У меня может быть больше 1000 group_id за день, это выходит 1 000 топиков в kafka..
Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону мне смотреть для решения этой проблемы..
P.S.
В целом старые очереди (где не было сообщений больше 24 часов) можно удалять.

Comment: Я не знаю про кафку ничего, но если вы на каждый groupId спавните поток на хосте, то это не есть хорошо. Я бы количество обработчиков ограничил каким то разумным числом (условно 5 штук) и разводил бы сообщения по какому нибудь hash(groupId)%5, то есть несколько групп могут обрабатываться одним обработчиком. В этом случае хост не должен падать при нагрузке и сообщения одной группы обрабатываются последовательно. Но еще раз, я не шарю, потому может ерунду написал :)

Comment: В твоём случае не нужно отдельный топик в Кафке на groupId. Создай 1 топик, разбей его на столько партиций, сколько хочешь гонять параллельных потоков. Сообщениям в  Кафке ставь messageKey=groupId. Это гарантирует, что сообщения с одинаковым groupId всегда будут попадать в одну и ту же партицию, а значит вычитываться будут строго последовательно.https://forum.confluent.io/t/what-should-i-use-as-the-key-for-my-kafka-message/312

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov благодарю! Так и поступил. Но столкнулся с проблемой -- kafka не балансирует между партициями (бывает, что в одну партицию падают сообщения с 4 ключами, на остальные по 1 :( ), Вы случайно не знаете, как можно реализовать балансировку? (Кроме, конечно, ручного выбора партиции при отправке из Бека)
Вы так же можете выставить Ваш ответ как решение и я отмечу его :)

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за замечание! Однако в моем случае не выйдет сделать нормальной асинхронности, потому что некоторые операции могут сильно заблокировать работу.. Приходится разграничивать на потоки

Comment: 4/1 - это небольшая разница, тaм выполняется простое `partition = messageKey.hashCode() % num_partitions` и нв большом разнообразии ключей это более менее работает. У тебя всего 200 ключей (==200 групп) и на таком малом числе вполне может быть перекос.

Comment: Если все сообщения генерируются на одном сервере в одном месте, то ты можешь написать свою функцию по аналогии с https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/RoundRobinPartitioner.java, которая для знакомого message_key возвращает запомненный partition,  а для незнакомого выбирает партицию, на которую назначено меньше всего ключей. Этот способ не гарантирует равномерного распределения всё равно, но может слегка улучшить ситуацию.